# Split and add <br> tag to concatenated dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string in javascript that looks like: 11/25/1612/02/1612/09/1606/03/17
The string can have many dates concatenated.

How can I place an HTML 
 tag between each date of that string so that the output will be 11/25/16 br 12/02/16 br 12/09/16 br 06/03/17

Thanks

Comment: Why on earth do you have that string? Are you *sure* you have that string? How did you *create* that string? It's a terrible string to do anything with.

Comment: This is Datatable Jquery print function https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/simple.html, it prints the table and I don't know why  it concatenates all my td inner html  to 1 element.

Comment: @oussamakamal Can you create a demo that shows the problem?

Comment: I think you are accessing an internal representation of the data.  I am certain there is a way to get the data as an array, but I haven't worked with datatables in a couple of years.

Comment: Derek, this is a sample: https://jsfiddle.net/Oussama1985/mhx8xL3u/   you can see that the dates are displayed as bullets in the second row, if you press Print you will see them inline and not one below the other.

Comment: @oussamakamal It seems the library is converting your list into a string. So instead of using `<ul>`s, you can first convert that manually to a normal string with `<br>`s and then pass it to `DataTable`.

Comment: I did but the library is still doing that concatenation

Comment: Datatables strips out HTML and CSS within table cells (e.g., https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/31081/datatables-print-view-doesnt-maintain-display-formatting-css). That's... unfortunate. This happens during export, before you have access to the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```js
console.log(
  '11/25/1612/02/1612/09/1606/03/17'.replace(/(?:\d{2}\/){2}\d{2}(?!$)/g, '$&<br>')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `match` and `join` functions:

```
s = "11/25/1612/02/1612/09/1606/03/17"
res = s.match(/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d/g).join("<br/>")
//res == "11/25/16<br/>12/02/16<br/>12/09/16<br/>06/03/17"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid using regex...
this solution is not very elegant, but it works.

```js
let string = '11/25/1612/02/1612/09/1606/03/17'
let chunklength = 8
let totalchunks = string.length / chunklength
let chunks = []

for (let start = 0, i = 1; i <= totalchunks; ++i, start += 8) {
  let chunk = string.substr(start, chunklength)
  console.log(chunk)
  chunks.push(chunk)
}
let newstring = chunks.join('<br>')
console.log(newstring)
```